# Compare 2 values in same row and same table using Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, field

Can anybody help me out, while my solution does not seem to work:

```
$this->db->where('stock <=','stock_min');
$res = $this->db->get("products")->result();
```

You see I want to compare the field 'stock' to be less than or equal to 'stock_min'...

Someone?

As requested the table-structure:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sub_of` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` int(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `slug` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `number` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `value` decimal(5,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `value_discount` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `yell` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `display_price` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `stock` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `stock_min` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `warned` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `relation` varchar(350) DEFAULT NULL,
  `supplier` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price_in` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `price_out` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `price_out_btw` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `active` smallint(6) DEFAULT '0',
  `display_from` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `display_till` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `seen` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `info_requested` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `inserted` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=322 ;
```

Comment: post the structure of the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->db->where('stock <= stock_min');
```

In your code the 'min_stock' is interpreted as the string 'min_stock' not the column. In the future when you have this kind of issues you can call `$this->db->last_query();` to see the exact query that is ran against the DB.